# Selenium - random "Command line server for the IE Driver has stopped working" after several hours

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-iedriver

I have several hundred selenium tests for my company's e-commerce site.  In particular, about half of them is checkout testing with small variances (singleship with visa, multiship with amex, etc).  I mention this because all of these tests use almost the exact same code, just with slight differences.

These tests are kicked off from Jenkins using Selenium Grid as a hub and being deployed to a Windows Server 2012 VM running Chrome and IE tests simultaneously.  After kicking off my tests, without fail after several hours I will get a browser popup saying `Command line server for the IE Driver has stopped working` and a button to `Close the program`.  This causes test execution to hang.

I have tried to upgrade to the latest version of the grid on the VM, and the latest version of the IE Driver Server.  I have also written a little rest server that runs `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM IEDriverServer.exe")` at the beginning of each test (I thought that perhaps too many windows open at one time caused the error, but even with this fix it didn't help).  I also tried adding `TabProcGrowth` to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main` to the registry, but that just caused multiple windows to open at the beginning of each test, breaking things further.

Additionally, I have implemented a retry analyzer that will retry failed tests.  After manually clicking `Close the program`, the test will restart and almost always pass.  Considering that, and the nature of the checkout tests, I don't think the issue is a code problem.

I have tried for days to solve this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!