# TestNG - execute method or fail if tests take too long?

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I have a set of maybe 500 selenium tests using the TestNG framework.

Occasionally, a particular test will hang for no apparent reason ([see my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46077330/1535349)) which will stop the tests from proceeding further.

If I manually close the browser, then that test will fail and the tests will resume.  I have a way to restart the browser if such an instance occurs, but I need a way for my code to know if it happens.

My best guess would be a timer where if a particular test takes longer than 15 minutes to execute I can just kill the browser, but I can't find a way to continually monitor each test for that trigger.

Answer (score 1):

You can use timeOut annotation, see [tutorial](https://dzone.com/articles/testng-test-annotation-%E2%80%93-using), for example :

```
@Test(timeOut = 2000)
```

Comment: There's no way it's that simple....going to implement this see what happens.  Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, when used in conjunction with a `retryanalyzer`,  it looks like this is causing more issues than it fixes.  I asked a new question.  Are you familiar with how to make those two TestNG feature play together?

Comment: timeOut only flags the test case in the results:

"[ERROR]   TestFile.TestCase » ThreadTimeout Method tests.TestFile.TestCase() didn't finish within the time-out 120000"

TestNG didn't terminate my test case. All I got was a message about it running too long.  While the documentation state, "Additionally, a time-out of ten seconds guarantees that none of the threads will block on this thread forever." that doesn't  appear to be true.  My test case hit the timeout and kept on going.