# Using TestNG's @Test timeout with retryAnalyzer

Tags: selenium, testng

I have several hundred selenium tests using the Selenium grid to a remote Windows VM from Jenkins acting as the hub.  I've been using a [RetryAnalyzer](http://www.seleniumeasy.com/testng-tutorials/execute-only-failed-test-cases-using-iretryanalyzer) for each of them for sometime, with great success.  But recent issues have caused tests to hang indefinitely - so I tried to implement the [timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46280810/testng-execute-method-or-fail-if-tests-take-too-long) feature on the @Test annotation (so it would look like this: `@Test(retryAnalyzer=MyRetryAnalyzer.class, timeOut=600000)`.

The issue is that with the timeout, as soon as test fails for any reason The entire suite fails almost immediately with every test throwing an `UnreachableBrowserException`.  If I remove the timeout, then it works correctly.

I am opening the WebDriver using TestNg's `@BeforeMethod` annotation, if that helps.

It feels like with the timeout set, and after a failure, then the timeout gets set to 0 on each test and when testng tries to retry the test, it can't with a timeout of 0 (this is just what it feels like however).

Edit - another crazy thing that's happening is I tried adding a `Thread.sleep(5000)` after quitting the webdriver thinking that might do something, but it instead threw a `InterruptedException: sleep interrupted` exception.  I've never seen Thread.sleep actually throw an error before. What is going on here?

Comment: Can you please show us some code that is causing this ? Without code, its hard to de-cipher as to what is going wrong.